# Sum of Data(end) in a cell array of timeseries

Tags: matlab

Given the code below:

```
% Generate some random data
n = 10;
A = cell(n, 1);
for i=1:n
    A{i} = timeseries;
    A{i}.Data = rand(100, 1);
    A{i}.Time = 1:100;
end
```

I would like to make the sum of `Data(end)` without explicitly writing a `for` loop. Is there a smart way to select `Data(end)` in all cells in a single line? `A{:}.Data(end)` does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) but that is essentially just a for loop wrapped up:

```
cellfun(@(x) x.Data(end), A)
```

Comment: +1, The same goes with `arrayfun`, `arrayfun(@(n) A{n}.Data(end), 1:numel(A))`. Again, just a for loop wrapped up. I guess cellfun is faster though.

Comment: My objective is to write less code. I don't have many fields in A{i} so speed is not a significant factor. Thanks!

Comment: @RobertP. I don't know about *faster* (I'd guess for loop outdoes them both) but `cellfun` is *simpler* in this case. Sometimes that `arrayfun` trick is necessary but in this case it's practically a textbook use case for `cellfun`.

Comment: @Dan, I agree, and as I said, I prefer Dan's answer! I wrote the arrayfun solution just to show that there are alternatives. =)

Comment: @remus check out nkjt's answer that uses comma separated lists rather than loops

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24752746/2338750), but for reference, I'll post an alternative using [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html). This is also just a for loop wrapped up to save keystrokes, but not necessarily time.

```
sum(arrayfun(@(n) A{n}.Data(end), 1:numel(A)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also extract all of the `Data` fields into a single matrix, which might be worth it if you're planning on doing multiple operations on it:

```
A2 = [A{:}];
A3 = [A2.Data];
sum(A3(end,:))
```

Comment: Mostly because that's what OP's looking to do, partly to demonstrate which way around the data ends up.

Comment: Would be nice if `[[A{:}].Data](end,:)` works without explicitly writing the intermediate variables. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but I think that's possible in Octave. One of the good, but very stupid features of Octave. Nice to be able to do it, but you can't run it in Matlab afterwards, effectively ruining the whole point. It's supposed to be compatible.